# Buildroot cross compile

Tags: cross-compiling, buildroot

I have a problem when I cross compile using the following command:

```
$ buildroot-2013.02/output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc                   \
  -o laa exemple.c                                                      \
   $(/home/adel/Bureau/buildroot-2013.02/output/host/usr/bin/pkg-config \
      --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0)
```

With the following console output:

```
sysroot/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so: warning: the use of OBSOLESCENT `utime' is \
 discouraged, use `utimes'
sysroot/usr/lib/libX11.so.6: warning: gethostbyname is obsolescent,        \
 use getnameinfo() instead.
```

It seems to compile fine.  Can the warnings cause problems when I execute the output file, nothing been displayed, so what's the problem and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

No, the warnings are harmless. They just tell you that libglib and libX11 use C library functions that are marked deprecated. But since the C library can't break the binary compatibility, those functions are still there and everything should work fine in terms of execution.